# Google Chart not working

Tags: c#, charts, google-visualization

i am using google charts for displaying statistics.I am sending a json data as follows to charts data. I am getting the chart finely but if you observe the values on Y axis those are not in order. How can i resolve this? Attaching the screenshot of graph as well.I will explain little more about the data, in database we have data for bedroom1 to bedroom 6 with their status as Occupied or Vacant. We need to show the statistics for them with in that particular financial year like how many occupied and how many vacant in my hotel.

```
[[["name","budjet1","budjet2","budjet3","budjet4","budjet5","Bedroom6","Bedroom3","Bedroom2","Bedroom1"
],["Occupied","26","17","13","5","4","1","0","0","0"],["Vacant","1","1","1","0","0","0","0","0","0"]
,["Future - Certain","2","3","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"]]]

function drawChart(response) {
            var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(response[0]);
            var options1 = {
                chart: {
                    title: 'Availability Status By Bedroom', },

            };

 var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material1'));
              chart.draw(data1, options1);
}
```

[Graph Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUtvS.png)

Comment: the values for `"budjet1","budjet2"...` need to be numbers, instead of strings (lose the quotes) -- `["Future - Certain",2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`

Comment: Thanks WhiteHat,

its working fine for me know

Answer (score 1):

the values for "budjet1","budjet2"... need to be numbers, instead of strings
(lose the quotes)

`["Future - Certain",2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`